# 111: Connection Refused

Tags: networking, apt, proxy, synaptic

When I attempt to install packages through sudo apt-get install, no matter what I try to install, it returns a 111: Connection Refused error.

The web browser appears to work, but not sudo apt-get install. I attempted to install Ruby, PHP, and open-shift RHC tools, and I also attempted to use Synaptic to update/install packages, and I was unable to.

I get errors similar to the following, every time:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main          /liby/libyaml  > /libyaml-0-2_0.1.4-3ubuntu3.1_i386.deb
Could not connect to 155.238.4.87:8080 (155.238.4.87). - connect (111: Connection refused)
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

I connect to my adsl router via wireless, and am running an image that i got from my university running on vmware, using Windows 10. The university used a proxy but I edited it out in the M2 setting file and edited firefox to auto detect proxy to get my internet working

Please can someone help me figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

See if there's a proxy set in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (or somewhere in `/etc/apt/apt/apt.conf.d`).

There'll be a file with a line something like: 
`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://155.238.4.87:8080";`

Comment the line(s) by putting a `#` at the beginning of it and try again.

Comment: I dont have either of those files, I only have one apt folder

Comment: think it was using a maven proxy before

Comment: I doubt apt-get was using a maven proxy - or at least I've never heard of such a thing...

Comment: I had to remove proxy setting in mavens settings.xml and change firefox to auto-detect proxy settings in order to access the internet but still get the same error when trying to download a package

Answer (score 3):

> Could not connect to x.x.x.x:8080

Connection to `IP:8080` indicates that you're using proxy.

Here are few suggestions:

- Check by: `apt-config dump | grep -i proxy`.
- If proxy is used, edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file or check for config files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` or find by `grep -ri proxy /etc/apt/`, then adjust or remove the proxy.
- To check the direct connection to `security.ubuntu.com`, run:

  ```
  curl http://security.ubuntu.com/ && echo Works
  ```

  To test the connection through proxy, run:

  ```
  curl -x http://PROXYIP:8080/ http://security.ubuntu.com/ && echo Works
  ```
- To debug networking for `apt-get` command, you can run:

  ```
  strace -f -e network apt-get update 2>&1 | grep -C10 refused
  ```
- Check your firewall rules and network configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this error by removing network settings.

I do :

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

If I see this

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://macth-with-your-ip-or-dns-setting:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://macth-with-your-ip-or-dns-setting:9999/";
```

I go to **network system settings** and choose **network** then select **Network Proxy Method** see drop-down menu, choose **manual** then DELETE all settings there. Click **Apply** to save the setting or configuration that you made.

In the terminal do

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

if there is no output, you have finished and you can `apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

1. First check `/etc/apt/apt.conf`: if you found `Acquire::http::proxy "http://x.x.x.x:8080/"` just commented it with (`#`) at the beginning of the line.
2. Then check `/etc/environment`: if you found `http_proxy="http://x.x.x.x:8080/"` just commented it with (`#`) on the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) version of Ubuntu, make sure you don't have any 3rd party Antivirus/firewalls enabled.

Try deactivating them and see if the connection goes back to normal.

There are known issues regarding 3rd party firewalls that do not behave well with WSL.

See the WSL GitHub issues [475](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/475) and [1720](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1720) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, I know, but had this same issue on 18.04 and none of the posts I found had the solution that eventually worked for us. Adding it to the collective...

```
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161). - connect (111: Connection refused)
```

No proxy/Not using a proxy. Ping out okay. `resolv.conf` only has internal nameserver entries.

Issue was resolved by removing a manual entry:

```
91.189.88.161    security.ubuntu.com
```

in `/etc/hosts`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The port you are trying to connect to is not open on the IP address that you are trying to connect to for one of the following reasons.

1. You are connecting to the wrong IP address. Use `nmap` on the server with hostname of `localhost` (`nmap localhost`) to check if the server is running properly in the port you want, and on the client with your server's public IP address to check if the destination port is open.
2. You did not open the port on your firewall successfully.
3. Your system is configured to use a local HTTP proxy for apt connections, and no such proxy is running. Many companies and higher education institutions have restrictions in place which includes a policy to control the types of websites you can access.

Answer (score -1):

1. In command prompt, enter `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf`
2. Delete (or comment out) the contents of the file, press Ctrl+O and then Ctrl+X
3. Enter `sudo apt update`
4. Resume doing what you were previously doing.